# Why a button with an image doesn't respect width and height settings

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm creating a button that will display an image instead of text, the problem is, the width and height is just ignored.
Why?

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="60" Height="60" Margin="0, -30, 0, 0" BorderThickness="0" >
    <Image Source="Assets/ic_play.png" Width="60" Height="60" Margin="0,-29, 0,0" />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button has `MinWidth`/`MinHeight` property by default (see question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24259935/2681948). The *Style* of the default button looks like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23858445/2681948).

So you will have to override those minimum values for single button (or define *Style* and use it among other buttons):

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="60" MinWidth="60" Width="60" Height="60" Margin="0, -30, 0, 0" BorderThickness="0" >
    <Image Source="Assets/ic_play.png" Width="60" Height="60" Margin="0,-29, 0,0" />
</Button>
```